# make[1]: *** [Makefile:349: test] Error 1

Tags: redis

I am installing Redis6 on Linux machine.
I executed following commands:

```
wget https://download.redis.io/releases/redis-6.0.14.tar.gz
tar xzf redis-6.0.14.tar.gz
cd redis-6.0.14
sudo make
```

I execute make test, however I am getting error.

```
"test_client_main $::test_server_port "
Killing still running Redis server 68335
Killing still running Redis server 68371
Killing still running Redis server 68404
Killing still running Redis server 68492
Killing still running Redis server 70207
Killing still running Redis server 70245
Killing still running Redis server 74095
Killing still running Redis server 77104  
make[1]: *** [Makefile:349: test] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/redis/redis-6.0.14/src'
make: *** [Makefile:6: test] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie studying redis, but the most common issue when installing redis6 version is gcc issue.
reids 6.0.x,6.1.x version requires gcc8.2 or higher.
It has been modified from redis6.2 and gcc 4.8 or higher is required.

Could you please check your gcc version first and post more error details if this is not your problem?

Comment: I had not installed the gcc.

Comment: I followed the below steps and it resolved the issue:                                                     
sudo yum -y install gcc make # install GCC compiler
cd /usr/local/src 
sudo wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
sudo tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz
sudo rm -f redis-stable.tar.gz
cd redis-stable
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
sudo make distclean
sudo make
sudo yum install -y tcl                                                                                                     
sudo make test